# Google App Script Calendar API - createAllDayEvent() method not working as expected

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps-script

I've opened an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=672&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Priority%20Component%20Owner) about (what I assume) is a bug in Google App Scripts but it doesn't look like its being monitored so I wondering if anyone has a work around for my problem.

In summary I am running a script (via a google spreadsheet) which attempts to put an entry in a Google Calendar I created.

```
function testCalendarAllDayEvent(){
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("od4434jhedv936p65gcbl3bjg@group.calendar.google.com");
  var calTimezone = calendar.getTimeZone();
  var scriptTimezone = Session.getTimeZone();
  var calendarevent = calendar.createAllDayEvent("Test Event", new Date(2011,7,1));
  var summary = calendarevent.getStartTime();
}
```

So the above code adds the "Test Event" on the 31st July 2011 instead of the 1st July. If I change it to 
`new Date (2011,7,2)`it puts it in on the 1st August 2011. So it seems to be 30 days out.
The reason I look at the time zones it to ensure they are the same. When I look at the `summary` variable value it is `Mon Aug 01 2011 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (IST)`

I don't want to blindly add 30 days to all dates as it will just end in tears. Does anyone know if what I am doing is incorrect? I've used Google examples as templates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) takes a zero-based month index.  So

`new Date(2011,7,1)` creates a Date of Aug 1 2011.

whereas

`new Date(2011,6,1)` creates a Date of July 1 2011.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply but I was working on something else. Thanks for the answer but that isn't the solution as `calendar.createAllDayEvent("Testt123t", new Date(2011,7,1))` creates the event on June 29 2011 not Aug 1 2011.